# MacOS-like file preview with spacebar for Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar, previews

I came across a question on Ask Ubuntu that mentioned that Ubuntu [ships with a similar feature](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-preview.html) to macOS' preview, where you can select a file and press the spacebar to get a preview of the file.

However, I am using Xubuntu 16.04 which is a blend of Linux that uses Xfce which has a different file manager (Thunar) and doesn't seem to support this feature. When I press the spacebar, it just opens the file the same way like double clicking on it would.

Is there a way to get this feature in Xubuntu?

Comment: That documentation you linked is for 16.10, the never development release. 16.04 doesn't seem to have this feature yet. At least it is not in my 16.04 with Unity desktop (default). You might want to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you'll have to install a different file manager though! If you're going to do that, however, you might as well just change your whole distribution.
Another way is to use Thunar's custom actions to create an option to open with ImageMagickQ16, (command line for this is "display") or it might already be on right click "open with" if installed. You can check your package manager to see if you can install it, if not. Works fine on my Xubuntu 16.04.2.
If you have no particular need to open these files in anything else you can even set it as default, by selection on right click of open with other application, set that as default for that type of file, so when you click on a file with certain file names it will pop up the "preview." Downside of this is if you really want to open another picture viewer as typical behavior,  you will then have to right click and select "open with" something else, such as Ristretto. (You can change it back with the same method, however.) 
 Also, those "previews" do not close automatically, if you preview a slew of photos you'll wind up with all of them open. Just be sure to click the X in ImageMagick to close each one after viewing.
That program has been around a LONG LONG time, since 1986 If I recall. You can even do basic editing in it if you'd like. However, it's mostly used as a backend for other programs, such as previewers for several file types, PDF viewers, RAW image viewers, etc. Interesting thing, it's on most Linux systems by default, and is usable in Windows (MS) systems as well.

Other file managers use Gloobus-preview or Gnome-Sushi to automate the process of having picture previews available in the file manager. I really really loved the old Marlin file manager for this, but it doesn't seem to work properly in its replacement, Pantheon. Previews work in Nautilus, but personally, never liked that one much, for other reasons.